# I can not identify the missing argument

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code to show the list of privileges for the object User1.

```
class User:
def __init__(self, f_name, l_name, age):
    self.f_name = f_name
    self.l_name = l_name
    self.age = age

def describe(self):
    print(f"The user {self.f_name} {self.l_name} has {self.age} years old person.")

def greet(self):
    print(f"Hi {self.f_name}, you are the Administer right now!")

class Privileges:
    def __init__(self, privileges):
        self.privileges = ['add post', 'del post', 'ban users']

    def show_privileges(self):
    print(f"These are the Admin list of privileges: {self.privileges}.")

class Admin(User):
    def __init__(self, f_name, l_name, age):
        super().__init__(f_name, l_name, age)
        self.privileges = Privileges()

user1 = Admin('Porco', 'Rosso', 42)
user1.privileges.show_privileges()
```

This is the output but I can not find this missing argument:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python_work\teste34.py", line 25, in <module>
        user1 = Admin('Porco', 'Rosso', 42)
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python_work\teste34.py", line 23, in __init__
        self.privileges = Privileges()
    TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'privileges'
    [Finished in 0.433s]
```

I would like to complement with a code I did before where there were no need to pass the argument:

```
    class User:
def __init__(self, f_name, l_name, age):
    self.f_name = f_name
    self.l_name = l_name
    self.age = age

def describe(self):
    print(f"The user {self.f_name} {self.l_name} has {self.age} years old person.")

def greet(self):
    print(f"Hi {self.f_name}, you are now the Admin!")

    class Admin(User):
        def __init__(self, f_name, l_name, age):
    super().__init__(f_name, l_name, age)
    self.privileges = ['add post', 'del post', 'ban users']

def show_privileges(self):
    print(f"These are SysOp list of privileges: {self.privileges}.")

    user1 = Admin('Porco', 'Rosso', 42)
    user1.describe()
    user1.greet()
    user1.show_privileges()
```

Comment: `self.privileges = Privileges()` you need to pass something in the `Privileges(___)` or remove `privileges` from `def __init__(self, privileges):`

Comment: The error message says it explicitly: "__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'privileges' - you're calling `Privileges` class (and thus its `__init__` method) without arguments in class `Admin`.

Comment: @SayandipDutta thanks but I was thinking that the list (self.privileges = ['add post', 'del post', 'ban users'])would be passed automatic. This is the reason to write instantiate a class as a method. No?

Comment: I will write an answer.

Comment: @Vinicivs added, please check.

Comment: @SayandipDutta thank you very much. I am still trying to understand but I became more confused since the code a wrote before did not need to pass anything. Could you check this other code in the end of post? It runs ok.

Answer (score 3):

```
    self.privileges = Privileges()
```

doesn't pass any arguments.

```
class Privileges:
    def __init__(self, privileges):
```

demands an argument named `privileges`. It never uses it though, so perhaps you just need to remove it, making it:

```
class Privileges:
    def __init__(self):
```

If it's supposed to have a default value, you want something like:

class Privileges:
    def **init**(self, privileges=('add post', 'del post', 'ban users')):
        self.privileges = list(privileges)

Note that you shallow copy whatever you were passed to avoid the problems with [mutable default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/364696) and similar issues if a user passes their own `list` (where you don't want your modifications to affect them, or vice-versa).

Answer (score 0):

According your comments, you were meaning to pass the argument in the `__init__` of class `Priviliges` implicitly. In order to do that, you needed a default argument:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, f_name, l_name, age):
        self.f_name = f_name
        self.l_name = l_name
        self.age = age

def describe(self):
    print(f"The user {self.f_name} {self.l_name} has {self.age} years old person.")

def greet(self):
    print(f"Hi {self.f_name}, you are the Administer right now!")

class Privileges:
    def __init__(self, privileges = ['add post', 'del post', 'ban users']):
        self.privileges = privileges

    def show_privileges(self):
        print(f"These are the Admin list of privileges: {self.privileges}.")

class Admin(User):
    def __init__(self, f_name, l_name, age):
        super().__init__(f_name, l_name, age)
        self.privileges = Privileges()

user1 = Admin('Porco', 'Rosso', 42)
user1.privileges.show_privileges()
```

Output:

```
These are the Admin list of privileges: ['add post', 'del post', 'ban users'].
```

**NOTE**

However, using mutable types as default argument is strongly discouraged.

Comment: Your default is [risking serious problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/364696).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I know, I should add not recommended in the answer body.